# Combinations and Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the probability that a poker hand has five cards each with a different rank?

P(5 cards different rank)= P(No pair)+ P(Straight)+ P(Flush)
$.50118+.00197+.00392= .50707 =50.7$ percent

This problem is a combination problem. For this problem I have $\binom{13}{5} * 4^5 $

Comment: Please start using MathJax when posting math. It really makes it easier on us to read, and it makes it more likely that you will get help. Please help us help you. I've edited your post again to add Math formatting. Please take some time to read up on MathJax:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: ok, I will try do that next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. I would have thought about it strictly as a combination problem. The denominator is the number of ways to choose $5$ cards, which is $\binom{52}{5}$. So I would simply have solved it as I did below, rather than breaking it up into cases.

$$\dfrac{ \binom{13}{5} * 4^{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$